# jQuery - check if mouse cursor is inside 2 elements (from inside a mouseover event)

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a tooltip function in which I have a mouseout event on 2 elements.
These two elements are child-parent (one into another).

Within this event I need to check if the mouse cursor is outside of both these 2 elements. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. In the `mouseover` event on the elements, you need to check to see if the mouse cursor is *outside* both elements? Did you mean *inside*? Or did you mean a `mouseout` event instead of `mouseover`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) you can use [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) for this:

```
$("#parentID").mouseleave(function() {
  alert("you have left the parent");
});
```

Where [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) fires when entering a child, [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) doesn't, it only fires when leaving the parent element that the event is bound to.

From the docs:

> The **mouseleave** event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event bubbling. If **mouseout** were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The **mouseleave** event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant.